# Scheduling event bridge events from private vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc, aws-event-bridge

We have a private VPC with no access to public internet. From ec2 instance inside this VPC, we are trying to schedule event bridge events. But i'm getting following exception from aws sdk :

***software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:83) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.21.41.jar:na]***

Our event is to post message to a specified SQS at a specific time. We have created VPC endpoint for our region following this documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-related-service-vpc.html

But still facing this issue. Any help to debug this or resolve this would be highly appreciated

We made sure that from our ec2 instance inside vpc, this endpoint is reachable - events.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com on port 443 by doing a telnet

Comment: Can you please share ec2 security group and vpc endpoint security group details